# Difference between 傷つくand 苦しむ

Tags: word-choice

Both have similar meanings of **"hurt"**

Comment: Are you asking about "to hurt" as in "to be in pain" or as in "to inflict pain"? Accordingly, you probably want to consider 傷つける or 苦しむ instead.

Comment: Yes, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

苦しむ is more like "to suffer", and it's used with a longstanding difficulty such as poverty, disease and bad reputation. 傷つく is "to be hurt" and it's usually used with a one-time shock (either physical or mental).

Examples:

- 2年間この病気で苦しんだ。
  I suffered from this disease for two years.
- 悪い噂に苦しんだ。
  I suffered from bad rumors.
- ピストルで撃たれて肩が傷ついた。
  I was shot with a pistol and my shoulder was hurt.
- 彼の冷酷な言葉に傷ついた。
  I was hurt by his cruel words.

The transitive versions are 苦しめる ("to bother/torment someone") and 傷つける ("to hurt someone/something"), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

苦しむ means to suffer or put up with something, such as a disease or bad situation (苦 has meanings of "suffering," "trial," "hardship," "pain," "bitterness," etc...)

傷つく can have a few different meanings; let's begin with the general meaning of 傷 itself which means "wound," "injury," "cut," "gash" etc. つく itself is a different verb which can also have a range of meanings, such as "affix," "arrive," "wear," "be attached." So 傷つく can mean to acquire an injury in the figurative or literal sense.

Comment: `while 傷つく more active (one causes injury to someone else)` I think you're mixing up つく and つける

Comment: You're right. I did get confused. I made the correction. I'm a beginner at this, so I need to learn to pay more attention. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!